# Big delays in RTP media when using android.net.rtp facilities

Tags: android, media, voip, rtp

I'm building a VOIP application for Android and use the built-in RTP facilities, android.net.rtp. Everything works fine, apart from the following issues:

- In the incoming RTP stream there are big delays (around 0.5 - 1 sec until I hear the other party) -notice that the outgoing stream reaches the other party instantly
- In the outgoing RTP stream there are small interruptions.

Keep in mind that for the AudioStream I'm using PCMU codec and so does the remote party.

Here are some key pieces of code:

**Initialise audio facilities (once):**

```
public class SoundManager implements AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {
    Context appContext;
    AudioManager audio;
    AudioStream audioStream;
    AudioGroup audioGroup;
    InetAddress localAddress;
    private static final String TAG = "SoundManager";

    public SoundManager(Context appContext, String ip){
        this.appContext = appContext;
        audio = (AudioManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        try {
            localAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
            audioGroup = new AudioGroup();
            audioGroup.setMode(AudioGroup.MODE_ECHO_SUPPRESSION);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Initialise AudioSession (once before the beginning of every call)**

```
public int setupAudioStream() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Setting up Audio Stream");
    try {
        audioStream = new AudioStream(localAddress);
        audioStream.setCodec(AudioCodec.PCMU);
        audioStream.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_NORMAL);
    }
    catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return audioStream.getLocalPort();
}
```

**Start streaming (once at the beginning of every call)**

```
public void startStreaming(int remoteRtpPort, String remoteIp) {
    audio.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

    // Request audio focus for playback
    int result = audio.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

    if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
        try {
            audioStream.associate(
                    InetAddress.getByName(remoteIp),
                    remoteRtpPort);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            audioStream.join(audioGroup);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot receive audio focus; media stream not setup");
    }
}
```

**Stop streaming (once at the end of every call)**

```
public void stopStreaming() {
    try {
        audioStream.join(null);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    audioGroup.clear();
    if (audioStream.isBusy()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "AudioStream is busy");
    }
    audioStream = null;
    audio.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);

    // Abandon audio focus when playback complete
    audio.abandonAudioFocus(this);
}
```

Finally, notice that in the Android console (logcat) I see these:

```
D/AudioGroup﹕ latency: output 400, input 64'
D/AudioGroup﹕ stream[56] is configured as PCMU 8kHz 20ms mode 0
D/AudioGroup﹕ stream[67] is configured as RAW 8kHz 32ms mode 0
```

Seems one of the streams has pretty big latency, plus one of them seems configured as RAW. Not sure if i'm interpreting them correctly though

Has anybody witnessed similar behaviour?

Best regards,
Antonis

Comment: hey mate, any findings?

Comment: I'm afraid not. In the end we changed to using webrtc for media :)